# Setting styles in Android

Tags: android

Hey guys I am new to development for the Android, I have a question for a project I am working on:

Using these styles to style my `actionbar`:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I get an error for both styles, they say:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/
 Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/
 Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
```

I am putting these in a separate `XML` file called themes.  In my style `XML` file I have the theme `android:Theme.Light`

If you could give me a suggestion or whatnot as to what is wrong here I would appreciate it!

David

Comment: change to `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

You are referring to the styles in your values/styles.xml and you do not have the style mentioned in styles.xml. You probable meant to refer to the one in the android style package like `@android:style/..`

Change to

```
 <resources>
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
             <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
         <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

    </style> 
</resources>
```

Comment: For the second style is tells me `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse requires API level 14 (current min is 11)`

Comment: And the first one tells me: `error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/
 Theme.Holo>Light.DarkActionBar'.`

Comment: @DavidBiga just a minute. checking

Comment: @DavidBiga it should be `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">` for the 2nd error its to typo error and yes your minsdk requires to be 14

Comment: So whats the issue I need to fix?

Comment: @DavidBiga change your min sdk to 14 in manifest. then change to parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"> in styles.xml

Comment: so I only have the issue with `         <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
` it tells me: `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:background' with value '@drawable/
 actionbar_background').`

Comment: @DavidBiga you need to have the drawable `actionbar_background` in the drawable folder? If not found you see that error.